# How to slow down change of view layout parameters?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an ImageView and which changes it's margins after some event occurs. For example, it goes full screen. Currently it happens instantly so it just snaps to full screen immediately. How can I slow down that happening? I want to snap to full screen in 2-3 second like animation.

I am not sure how to start as google doesn't give me results for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `PropertyAnimator`, read it more on its official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

What it does is basically calculate your `ImageView`s properties and then it would set them gradually over a period of time. You could set the duration, the `Interpolator` that it will use, and even repeat it if you choose to.

Comment: @user3339562, hey that's what SO is all about. No need to thank me. :) However, if you're satisfied with my answer, could you kindly accept it?